# Using Java in Weka tool

Tags: weka

Now I am working with weka tool using java in eclipse. The problem is that I have already added the external jar file named `weka.jar` in the build path of my java project. I have already tried their instruction how to add external jar file of weka in Eclipse. But when I run the project, Eclipse show me that :

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No source has been
>   specified at
>   weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.getDataSet(ArffLoader.java:1003)at
>   arfftocsv.main.main(main.java:11)

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here isn't that Java can't find the `weka.jar`, it's that you called `ArffLoader.getDataSet` but the data file you passed can't be found. That could be anything from the file not being in the location you think to a typo to you tring to load the data from the classpath but having your path set incorrectly.